how to get the publication name and status of it through Catia vb scripting
I am trying to create macro that can detect publication status. reference image. you can see in reference image there is publication at bottom of Catia tree, now I want to get the publication name and its status which is same as publication window in reference image. any suggestions would be apricate.

The publications are accessible via the publications-Collection of the product. Each publication has the property .Name. According to the documentation there is no property for the status.

'Edit : I don't know how to access the information you are requesting.  I use Windows UI Automation to get all informations you need, but using .Net.
Maybe try this github.
https://github.com/mhumpher/UIAutomation_VBA
In VBA, you seem to be able to access all the buttons except what is in red in the image below.

What i tried:
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWndParent As LongPtr, ByVal hWndChildAfter As LongPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long



Private hWndList() As LongPtr
Private iListCount As Integer

Sub CatMain()

'Initialize your datas assuming you have a CatPart open

Dim activeDoc As PartDocument
Dim oPart As Part
Dim oProd As Product

Set activeDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument
Set oPart = activeDoc.Part
Set oProd = activeDoc.Product

If oProd.Publications.Count = 0 Then End

'Open the Publication Window and wait for 300ms to be displayed
CATIA.StartCommand "Publication"
Call Sleep(400) 'you need a Pause. Please improve this.
'mainWindowHandle need to be different of 0

'Get the Publication Window
Dim mainWindowHandle As LongPtr
mainWindowHandle = FindWindow("#32770", "Publication")


'to be deleted when you will be OK with your Pause
If mainWindowHandle = 0 Then
    MsgBox "please add a Pause after the startcommand"
    End
End If

'Get the OK button
Dim buttonOK As LongPtr
buttonOK = FindControlHandleByTextAndClass(mainWindowHandle, "OK", "Button")

'test
Dim test As LongPtr
test = FindControlHandleByTextAndClass(mainWindowHandle, "test", "test") 'to loop on each controls

'Example click on OK button
SendMessage buttonOK, &HF5, 0, 0
SendMessage buttonOK, &HF5, 0, 0 'why twice works ?

End Sub

Public Function GetTextFromHandle(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As String
    Dim textLength As Long
    Dim textBuffer As String

    textLength = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd)

    If textLength > 0 Then
        textBuffer = Space(textLength + 1)
        GetWindowText hWnd, textBuffer, textLength + 1
        GetTextFromHandle = Left(textBuffer, textLength)
    Else
        GetTextFromHandle = ""
    End If
End Function


Private Function FindControlHandleByTextAndClass(ByVal hWndParent As LongPtr, ByVal controlText As String, ByVal controlClass As String) As LongPtr
    Dim hWndChild As LongPtr
    Dim sWindowText As String
    Dim sClassName As String

    ' Get the handle of the first child window
    hWndChild = FindWindowEx(hWndParent, 0, vbNullString, vbNullString)
    
    ' Loop through all child windows
    Do While hWndChild <> 0
        ' Get the window text
        sWindowText = Space(255)
        GetWindowText hWndChild, sWindowText, Len(sWindowText)
        
        ' Get the class name
        sClassName = Space(255)
        GetClassName hWndChild, sClassName, Len(sClassName)
        
        ' Trim the excess spaces
        sWindowText = Trim(sWindowText)
        sClassName = Trim(sClassName)
        
        'MsgBox sWindowText
        'MsgBox sClassName
        

        ' Check if the window text and class name match the specified criteria
        If Left(Trim(sWindowText), Len(Trim(sWindowText)) - 1) = controlText And Left(Trim(sClassName), Len(Trim(sClassName)) - 1) = controlClass Then
            FindControlHandleByTextAndClass = hWndChild
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        ' Recursively search in the child window
        Dim recursiveHandle As LongPtr
        recursiveHandle = FindControlHandleByTextAndClass(hWndChild, controlText, controlClass)
        If recursiveHandle <> 0 Then
            ' If found in the child window, return the handle
            FindControlHandleByTextAndClass = recursiveHandle
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        ' Move to the next child window
        hWndChild = FindWindowEx(hWndParent, hWndChild, vbNullString, vbNullString)
    Loop
    
    ' If not found, return 0
    FindControlHandleByTextAndClass = 0
End Function


That's Greate saving answer for me. Thank you. can you please explain me how to proceed that DataGrid control, containing data items. I am very new to this.

what is DataGrid control is it "SysListView32" ?

Each items of the window contains a number (named Handle) and controlType (in your case : window, DataGrid, dataitem and ControlType.Edit). You can cast the Handle to an AutomationElement and getting its name. It will return then the text you Can sée in thé window

can you please suggest where to learn this UI automation on vb script

After some tests, i confirm you can not access to the handles of the grid. All buttons are available but not informations you need. UIAutomation with .Net allows you to access informations of the datagrid. You maybe can try this repo : https://github.com/mhumpher/UIAutomation_VBA

@MeghaP I eddited the Post if it can help.

Great, I got it, this helps me a lot. I appreciate your support.
